# Unable to redirect to home page after Login with Facebook

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic4, facebook-login, angular-router

I am trying to redirect to My home page after the Facebook Login, It successfully returns the token which is stored in localStorage but after that, it stays on the login page and doesn't redirect.

```
loginWithFB() {
    this.facebook.login(['public_profile', 'user_friends', 'email']).then((res: FacebookLoginResponse) => {

        this.facebook.api('me?fields=id,name,email,first_name,last_name', []).then(profile => {
            let data = {email: profile['email'], first_name: profile['first_name'], last_name: profile['last_name'], input_token:  res.authResponse.accessToken, phone: '1234567890'};
                   
            this.api.loginWithFacebook(data).then((res) => {
                this.checkLoginResFB(res);
            }, (err) => {
               console.log("Error in API");
               console.log(err);
            });
        });
    })
    .catch(e => console.log('Error logging into Facebook', e));
}

checkLoginResFB(res) {
    if (res.success == false) {
        console.log("unable to login");
        console.log(res.message);
    } else {
        console.log("login successfull");
        localStorage.setItem('token', JSON.stringify(res.token));
        this.router.navigateByUrl('/home');             //Redirect to Home Page
    }
}
```

Comment: Try: `this.router.navigate(['/home']);`

Comment: @NajamUsSaqib did that doesn't work

Comment: are you getting any error?

Comment: no there's no error

Comment: Hey @Pratik. Try navigating to any other component and see if it's working or not

Comment: also can you share your routing module file too

Comment: `const routes: Routes = [ 
   { path: 'add-pet', loadChildren: './add-pet/add-pet.module#AddPetPageModule', canActivate: [AuthGuardService] } 
];`

Comment: I have tried everything and it's not redirecting on any other route, the router works fine in other methods but shows issues in this. is this because of some restriction by Facebook?

Answer (score 0):

The router isn't working for some reason I don't know but vanilla javascript does
`window.location.replace('/home');`